# My python code does what it is intended to do, but breaks/keeps going with the try/catch blocks?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

```
#A 0-50 Units is multiplied by $0.59 (multiply by 0.59)
#B Up to 150 Units (minus 50 and multiply remaning by 0.65)
#C Greater than 150 Units(minus 150(first 150 = $94.50) and multiply remaining by 0.68)
#D All Residential charges are fixed @ $13.00(always add $13)
                
print ("      *        SKELEC Electricity Bill Calculator        *       ")

def main():
    
    while True:
        try:
            prev_month = float(input("Enter the meter reading for the previous month\n"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value entered. Please try again.")
            continue
        
    if prev_month < 0:
            print("Please enter a valid reading.")
            main()
            
    while True:
        try:
            pres_month = float(input("Enter the meter reading for the current month\n"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value entered. Please try again.")
            continue
        
    if pres_month < 0:
            print("Please enter a valid reading.")
            main()

    if pres_month < prev_month:
            print("Present month value is lower than previous month value")
            main()

    units_kwh = pres_month - prev_month #Variable for the subtraction of present month and previous month
    
    print("Usage = ", units_kwh,"kw/h")

    if units_kwh <= 50: #Argument for 0-50 kwh units
        Energy_charge = units_kwh * 0.59
        print("Your charge for the month is, $", Energy_charge)

    elif units_kwh > 50 and units_kwh <= 150: #Argument for units up to 150kwh
            units_fifty = units_kwh - 50
            Energy_charge = (units_fifty * 0.65 + 29.50) + 13.00
            print("Your charge for the month is, $", Energy_charge)


    elif units_kwh > 150: #Argument for units over 150kwh
            Energy_charge = ((units_kwh - 150) * 0.68 + 94.50) + 13.00
            print("Your charge for the month is, $", Energy_charge)
            
    print("Residential Charge of $13.00 added")

            
main()
```

Everything works well, but if an incorrect value is entered at first(such as characters), the code unwantedly loops once it gives the final result. I've tried moving the try/catch blocks outside of the loop, double checking my conditional statements and proofreading to see how the code could loop in such a way. I'm convinced the problem lays in the try/catch blocks, but I'm fairly new to coding with Python so I am unsure of how to fix this?

Comment: If you enter e. g. letters instead of a number for a meter reading, the code continues to ask until a number is entered. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Hint: The problem isn't in the try-except-blocks but in calling of "main()" in the function.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, when the code detects a character for a meter reading, that is its intended purpose, but it causes the code to ask for the reading again when the calculations are already done. I've also put the calling of "main()" functions at the end of the conditions because nested loops were not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a couple changes to improve the code:

- If the user enters a negative number, raise an exception
- Add an outer `while` loop for the `pres_month < prev_month` condition

Try this code:

```
def main():
    
    while True:  # pres_month < prev_month
    
        while True:
            try:
                prev_month = float(input("Enter the meter reading for the previous month\n"))
                if prev_month < 0: raise ValueError()
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid value entered. Please try again.")
            
        while True:
            try:
                pres_month = float(input("Enter the meter reading for the current month\n"))
                if pres_month < 0: raise ValueError()
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid value entered. Please try again.")
            
        if pres_month < prev_month:
                print("Present month value is lower than previous month value")
        else:
                break  # data is valid
```